# How to drag and drop the element using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Here I need to automate and reduce the bar to 50% that is I should make it to move into the middle.

[Slider Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DJgB.png)

Html for whole slider

```
<div class="LayerCategoryDetailSidebar_opacityBox__3Lw7t"><div class="LayerCategoryDetailSidebar_opacityRow__hKVms"><div class="rc-slider ghSlider"><div class="rc-slider-rail"></div><div class="rc-slider-track" style="left: 0%; right: auto; width: 48%;"></div><div class="rc-slider-step"></div><div tabindex="0" class="rc-slider-handle" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="0.48" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 48%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div><div class="rc-slider-mark"></div></div><div class="LayerCategoryDetailSidebar_categorySwitch__HfcuU" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; text-align: left; opacity: 1; direction: ltr; border-radius: 12px; transition: opacity 0.25s ease 0s; touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); user-select: none;"><div class="react-switch-bg" style="height: 24px; width: 40px; margin: 0px; position: relative; background: rgb(243, 119, 53); border-radius: 12px; cursor: pointer; transition: background 0.25s ease 0s;"></div><div class="react-switch-handle" style="height: 22px; width: 22px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 50%; position: absolute; transform: translateX(17px); top: 1px; outline: 0px; border: 0px; transition: background-color 0.25s ease 0s, transform 0.25s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease 0s;"></div><input type="checkbox" role="switch" checked="" style="border: 0px; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; position: absolute; width: 1px;"></div></div><div class="LayerCategoryDetailSidebar_opacityInfo__1bBk3">Transparency</div></div>
```

Please help me with python selenium.

[Need Output As](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqbwn.png)

i.e Round button reduced into half.

Comment: do you have any example website ?

Comment: No, what should i provide you, Please tell me

Comment: any website or code where this slider is available

Comment: Please check i have updated HTML for whole slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve it in this way, Thanks for the help.

```
ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(slider_element).move_by_offset(-100, 0).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the selenium automation with pyautogui, in that way you'll be able to control mouse movements like dragging and more.

You can read more about the mouse functions in PyAutoGUI website in this link:

[Mouse Control Fucntions - PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)

Comment: i was unable to find it out perfect to my result output..

Answer (score 0):

```
#Find slider elements
slider_container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#nc_1__scale_text > span")
slider = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#nc_1_n1z")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
#Perform sliding action
actions.move_to_element(slider).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(slider_container.size['width'], 0).release().perform()

#most sliders are inside iframes(popups),make sure you switch driver to that iframe before proceeding above
```